# SAML Response not reaching to SuccessHandler

Tags: java, saml, saml-2.0, spring-saml

I am using Spring SAML extension for enabling SAML support with OKTA IdP, have used  automatic metadataGenerator filter for SP metadata of my application,
I have also configured the Okta App's Single Sign On URL as per the generated metadata's AssertionConsumerService location.

Once I deploy my application and hit any URL in browser, it redirects to Okta login page and on successful login page it redirects to configured Sign On URL, which is working as expected, but every time the error handler page is open and the control never reaches to the registered SAMLUserDetailsService's loadUserBySAML method.

Tried everything but everytime the error handler page gets open on successful redirection.

The complete configuration is done through Java Configuration URL as mentioned in the Spring SAML Extension documentation.

Comment: @Vladimír-Schäfer please let me know whether Spring SAML can be integrated into simple web applications, not secured through Spring Security

Answer (score 0):

to be redirecting or landing on /error one would have to assume an error is being generated post auth somehow. are there any stacktraces on the server side?